# CMS Error 500 error when sending message using AT command

Tags: at-command

I'm trying to send an SMS using AT command at Hyper Terminal,
   i'm using HUAWEI E1552
   and I'm getting this Error CMS ERROR 500, 
   i need help to figure out what causes this error.. thanks

Comment: Hi, can you please post your AT command dialogue?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread but for future reference I guess this will be useful:

**+CMS ERROR 500** basically refers to unknown error and it is hard to determine, but mostly this may refer to one of the following situations based on Modem or Operator:

- No or weak network coverage - move modem somewhere with a better signal reception
- Insufficient SIM card credit - charge SIM
- International phone number required - send recipient's number to modem with country
  code

for a full description of **+CMS ERROR n** you may visit [**here**](http://www.nowsms.com/gsm-modem-cms-error-code-list) or [**here**](http://ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=598)

Answer (score 1):

This is an unknown issue. The modem does not specify due to which reason the error occurs. I faced the same issue but when I restarted the system, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was that the moden had no IMEI number. It was receiving SMS messages but when I try to send one message, receive CMS ERROR 500.

Answer (score 0):

Add country code to phone number like **+96**------- if no balance and network signals issue

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by your provider blocking message sending. I tested the SIM in a regular phone and it could make calls but not send messages.